# How do I update specific rows in Google Spreadsheets using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script

What needs to happen is that from my React web app there's this form and data inputted should be sent to Google Spreadsheet.

1. Is there away to avoid using Timestamp when inserting new data in the spreadsheet?
2. How do I update a SPECIFIC row? 
   For example, i have Joe and I need to update his number to 456

```
| NAME  |  NUMBER | 
|-------|---------|
|Joe    |123      |
|Brian  |420      |
|Raine  |143      |
```

How do I do this coming from the web app?

I've tried this but still no luck

https://mashe.hawksey.info/2018/02/google-apps-script-patterns-conditionally-updating-rows-of-google-sheet-data-by-reading-and-writing-data-once/

This is from the web app with some code in the `componentDidMount()`

This code is used to the form data and to prevent the page from redirecting to the App script link. Basically it stays on the page and even reloads the form.

```
    componentDidMount() {

        console.log("Contact form submission handler loaded successfully.");
        // bind to the submit event of our form
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form.gform");
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            forms[i].addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
        }


        //document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);

        function validateHuman(honeypot) {
            if (honeypot) {  //if hidden form filled up
                console.log("Robot Detected!");
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("Welcome Human!");
            }
        }

        // get all data in form and return object
        function getFormData(form) {
            var elements = form.elements;
            var honeypot;

            var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter(function (k) {
                if (elements[k].name === "honeypot") {
                    honeypot = elements[k].value;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }).map(function (k) {
                if (elements[k].name !== undefined) {
                    return elements[k].name;
                    // special case for Edge's html collection
                } else if (elements[k].length > 0) {
                    return elements[k].item(0).name;
                }
            }).filter(function (item, pos, self) {
                return self.indexOf(item) === pos && item;
            });

            var formData = {};
            fields.forEach(function (name) {
                var element = elements[name];

                // singular form elements just have one value
                formData[name] = element.value;

                // when our element has multiple items, get their values
                if (element.length) {
                    var data = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                        var item = element.item(i);
                        if (item.checked || item.selected) {
                            data.push(item.value);
                        }
                    }
                    formData[name] = data.join(', ');
                }
            });

            // add form-specific values into the data
            formData.formDataNameOrder = JSON.stringify(fields);
            formData.formGoogleSheetName = form.dataset.sheet || "responses"; // default sheet name
            //formData.formGoogleSend = form.dataset.email || ""; // no email by default

            console.log(formData);
            return { data: formData, honeypot };
        }

        function handleFormSubmit(event) {  // handles form submit without any jquery
            event.preventDefault();           // we are submitting via xhr below
            var form = event.target;
            var formData = getFormData(form);
            var data = formData.data;

            // If a honeypot field is filled, assume it was done so by a spam bot.
            if (formData.honeypot) {
                return false;
            }

            disableAllButtons(form);
            var url = form.action;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            // xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                console.log(xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                form.reset();

                return;
            };
            // url encode form data for sending as post data
            var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function (k) {
                return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
            }).join('&');
            xhr.send(encoded);
        }

        function disableAllButtons(form) {
            var buttons = form.querySelectorAll("button");
            for (var i = 0; i > buttons.length; i++) {
                buttons[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }


    }
```

This is the snippet form in the web app

```
<form className="gform" method="POST"
                    action="GOOGLE APP SCRIPT">
                    <div className="row Late-body-container">
                        <div className="col-6">
                            <select name="Message" className="form-control reason-text" id="selectLateReason" onClick={this.checkOption} onChange={this.loaded}>
                                <option value="--">--</option>
                                <option value="Sick Leave">Sick Leave</option>
                                <option value="Emergency Leave">Emergency Leave</option>
                                <option value="Family Affairs">Family Affairs</option>
                                <option value="To travel">To travel</option>
                                <option value="Other reasons">Other reasons</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-send" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" >Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and then finally this is the Google app script code

```
/******************************************************************************
 * This tutorial is based on the work of Martin Hawksey twitter.com/mhawksey  *
 * But has been simplified and cleaned up to make it more beginner friendly   *
 * All credit still goes to Martin and any issues/complaints/questions to me. *
 ******************************************************************************/

// if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
// var TO_ADDRESS = "example@email.net";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
// uses an array of keys if provided or the object to determine field order
function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  if (!order) {
    order = Object.keys(obj);
  }

  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

// sanitize content from the user - trust no one 
// ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)
function sanitizeInput(rawInput) {
   var placeholder = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(" ");
   placeholder.appendUntrusted(rawInput);

   return placeholder.getContent();
 }

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }

    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;

    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // hold off up to 30 sec to avoid concurrent writing

  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it

    // select the 'responses' sheet by default
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var oldHeader = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var newHeader = oldHeader.slice();
    var fieldsFromForm = getDataColumns(e.parameters);
    var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp

    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);

      // mark as stored by removing from form fields
      var formIndex = fieldsFromForm.indexOf(field);
      if (formIndex > -1) {
        fieldsFromForm.splice(formIndex, 1);
      }
    }

    // set any new fields in our form
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsFromForm.length; i++) {
      var field = fieldsFromForm[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      newHeader.push(field);
    }

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // update header row with any new data
    if (newHeader.length > oldHeader.length) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, newHeader.length).setValues([newHeader]);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return;
  }

}

function getDataColumns(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(function(column) {
    return !(column === 'formDataNameOrder' || column === 'formGoogleSheetName' || column === 'formGoogleSendEmail' || column === 'honeypot');
  });
}

function getFieldFromData(field, data) {
  var values = data[field] || '';
  var output = values.join ? values.join(', ') : values;
  return output;
}
```

As mentioned earlier 
I have Joe and I need to update his number to 456

```
| NAME  |  NUMBER | 
|-------|---------|
|Joe    |123      |
|Brian  |420      |
|Raine  |143      |
```

so the Expected result should be that

```
| NAME  |  NUMBER | 
|-------|---------|
|Joe    |456      |
|Brian  |420      |
|Raine  |143      |
```

Additional note:
The code works but when I insert new data 
I can't get rid of the Timestamp. How do I get rid of it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm dividing this answer in two parts:

**1. Get rid of the Timestamp**

As you see in your Google Appscript code:

```
var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
```

You just have to remove the new Date() function at leave it as an empty array declaration:

```
var row = []; //There is no first element yet.
```

Right after this there is a for loop whose index is starting from 1 to avoid the Timestamp, but since we  have removed it there is no need to start at 1, so we have to change it.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // Now we start at 0 instead of 1
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      ....
```

**2. Updating a cell depending on the condition**

Since you already know the Name's condition (Joe) to update the Number, we just have to compare the values of each cell in A with the String `'Joe'`:

[image]

```
function updateCell() {

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //this line is not necessary if you just paste this code in yours

  var names = doc.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); //We store all the names from A2 to the last one
  var newValue = '456';

  for (var n = 2; n < names.length + 2; n++){ //We start at 2 since A1 and B1 are the headers of the table

    if (names[n - 2] == 'Joe'){ //But the array's first position is 0, so we deduct 2 form n.

      doc.getRange("B" + (n)).setValue(newValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow this is great @Jescanellas

it works and the only thing I need to change is 

```
//output captures the Name and matches Joe in column name
 if (names[n - 2] == output){ 

      doc.getRange("A" + (n)).setValue(newValue); // change this to value taken in web app
        }
```

I changed it to output so the name 'Joe' matches the one coming from the 'Joe' in web app

but I'm still confused on how to update the 'Number' from it coming from the form in web app

```
 var newValue = '456'; 
```

newValue has to capture the 'Number' coming from the web app

Comment: I don't recommend you to use "output" as it's value indirectly depends of `oldHeader[i]`, which value changes every time the loop runs. I don't know the form parameters but I guess they are stored in `e.parameters`, so you can do something like `var name = getFieldFromData(0, e.parameters)` and `var number = getFieldFromData(1, e.parameters)]`. As I said I don't know what's in there, so do a `Logger.log(e.parameters)` to find out the position of Name and Number.

Comment: It works! i've done it as `var name = getFieldFromData('Name', e.parameters)`

one more thing how do I save it also as a note? Like when I'd "insert note"